# Extract LUIS intent and score and train the LU from LUIS portal instead of from composer UI

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I am exploring Composer. I already use bot-framework c# model in Azure that connects with LUIS. We developed a one step FAQ bot (not multi-turn conversations) with only one main dialog. We used to extract the Luis intent and score whenever users type a text. We get answer from a SharePoint list for FAQs by passing the identified LUIS Intent as a column filter.

Is it possible to do the same in Composer to get the intent identified and score for each input we get from user.?

Also, instead of training the LU model in composer, can we train the utterances in the LUIS portal and consume the same intent/score in composer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use Luis inside Bot Framework Composer to recognize intents and do entity extractions. Bot Framework Composer allows you to put conditions on the recognized intents which you can use to make sure the next steps only fire when the score is >= x.

You can see how to use this in action and how the scoring works here (starting at 27:38):
https://youtu.be/ZNcfIgO8biw?t=1658

You can still make changes in the Luis portal, but at this time this is not recommended as  your changes will be overwritten the next time you publish to Luis via Bot Framework Composer. If you make changes in the Luis portal directly, make sure to export the .lu and re-integrate your Luis model in Bot Framework Composer to not lose your changes.